# Кодировка SOAP-сообщения

Tags: java, кодировка, веб-служба, jax-ws

Используя JAX-WS, написал веб-сервис, который отправляет строку:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@HandlerChain(file = "handler_chain.xml") 
public interface ServiceStyleRPC {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getAllShops")
    public String getAllShops(); 
}

@WebService(serviceName = "ServiceStyleRPC", endpointInterface = "by.bsuir.ws.ServiceStyleRPC")
public class ServiceStyleRPCImpl implements ServiceStyleRPC {

    @EJB 
    LogicRPC logicRPC;

    @Override
    public String getAllShops() {
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

        List<Shop> shops = logicRPC.getAllShops();
        for(Shop shop: shops) {
            try {
                JSONObject shopObject = new JSONObject();
                shopObject.put("id", shop.getId().toString());
                shopObject.put("name", shop.getName());
                shopObject.put("address", shop.getAddress());
                response.put(shopObject);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();   
            } 
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

В результате работы этого сервиса на glassfish4 SOAP запрос имеет вид:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getAllCategories xmlns:ns2="http://ws.test.by/"/>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Т.е. запрос в UTF-8 вроде как приходит. При формировании ответа на это сообщение кидается ошибка

> WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message :
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.; Refer to the server log for
>   more details

Для сервиса настроил HandlerChain, в котором явно указываю какую кодировку использовать:

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outbound = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outbound) {
        try {
            context.getMessage().setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        } catch (SOAPException ex) {}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Но это не помогает. Строка, возвращаемая из сервиса, содержит кириллицу и из-за этого все ломается. Может знает кто, как с этим побороться?